# eliminate product terms in equation

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I would like to eliminate all terms that contain the product of  dxy, dwz, and dxz, i.e. the final result should read as dxy +b dwz+ c dxz. Thanks in advance for any hint.

```
a dxy +b dwz+ c dxz+e dxy dwz +f dxy dxz +g dwz dxz + h dxy dxz dwz
```

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.
Why not choosing a meaningful name?

Comment: @user58765 Can you check the post that Carl cited and say if it helps to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the linked question:

```
expr = a dxy +b dwz+ c dxz+e dxy dwz +f dxy dxz +g dwz dxz + h dxy dxz dwz;

Normal @ Series[
    expr /. v:(dxy|dwz|dxz) -> v t,
    {t, 0, 1}
] /. t->1
```

> b dwz + a dxy + c dxz

Answer (score 0):

Or this way

```
expr = a dxy + b dwz + c dxz + e dxy dwz + f dxy dxz + g dwz dxz + 
       h dxy dxz dwz // Expand;

prodterms = Apply[Times, Subsets[{dxy, dwz, dxz}, {2, 3}], 2]

(*   {dwz dxy, dxy dxz, dwz dxz, dwz dxy dxz}   *)

expr /. Thread[prodterms -> 0]

(*   b dwz + a dxy + c dxz   *)
```